# Unable to identify elements in Appium inspector for Pega iOS app

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, appium-ios

I'm unable to identify elements using Appium inspector. When I click on any objects, the whole frame is getting selected.I am not able to identify each element uniquely.

I am using Appium 1.17.1-1 Device : iPhone 6S iOS version : 12.2

[image: Appium Inspector view]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this was solved for me by adding `snapshotMaxDepth = 63` and `customSnapshotTimeout= 50000` in capabilities a full example of the capabilities I used:

```
{
   "platformName":"iOS",
   "browserName":"",
   "appium:deviceName":"iPhone 14 Pro Max",
   "appium:platformVersion":"16.4",
   "appium:automationName":"XCUITest",
   "appium:showIOSLog":false,
   "buildId":"com.app.name”,
    “appium:settings”: {
        “snapshotMaxDepth”: 62,
        “customSnapshotTimeout”: 50000,
      },
}
```

IMPORTANT!! for now there is a bug that snapshotMaxDepth doesn't work for more than 62 for instance if you try with `“snapshotMaxDepth”: 63` it won't work

Answer (score -1):

Yes it sometimes happen to block all the child elements. Try to find it from the Source tab and see if your expcted element is selected.